# Spring Integration Java DSL .handle(String beanName, String methodName)

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

I have seen in many cases the `.handle("someBean", "someMethod")` EIP method, playing vast role in the integration flows. I can understand that it is just a Service Activator in the former XML Config, but I need some clarification on how to create this bean and what does the `someMethod` return. Also, in which cases do I have to use `.handle(...)`? Maybe a completed example using Java DSL should work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed correctly the `.handle("someBean", "someMethod")` is fully equal to the `<int:service-activator ref="someBean" method="someMethod"/>`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#service-activator-namespace.

That means that you should have `someBean` definition for service invocation in the `someMethod`. For example you need to perform simple logic to convert `payload` of the incoming message to the upper case and return the result:

```
class MyService {

   public String someMethod(String payload) {
        return payload.toUpperCase();
   }

}
```

The return of this method becomes as a `payload` of the outbound message to the next EIP endpoint in your `IntegrationFlow` definition.

Everything what you see in the Reference Manual is fully true for Java DSL. In particular all the rules for the `<service-activator>` or `@ServiceActivator` are applied for this `.handle()`.

Comment: Thank you Artem for your prompt answer. Is there the need to annotate the `someMethod` with `@Bean`? Also, I can perform the same logic with the transform EIP method, so could you give another example of the `.handle(...)` usage? In which cases to I have to strictly use `.handle(...)`?

Comment: No, we need `@Bean` only indeed for beans, e.g. bean methods in the `@Configuration` file. You already have your `someBean` as bean. The service method can fully be without any annotations. Another sample of `.handle()` in contradiction of `.transform()` is like direct usage of the `JdbcTemplate` from your method. Right, you can do that with transformer too, but would be better to distinguish the logic between appropriate components. If that is not about transformation, the `.handle()` is for you! Plus bear in mind that `.handle()` doesn't require a reply, but `.transform()` does.